# Can't establish a connection to the VPN gateway IP

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, strongswan, cisco-vpn

I have just setup a site-to-site vpn between a Strongswan instance and an AWS VPN Gateway, as the follows:

```
1.1.1.1 <-----> Strongswan (2.2.2.2) <---> AWS (VPC 172.0.0.0/8)
```

From the AWS, I can ping IPs in 1.1.1.1.
From the Strongswan instance I can also ping EC2 on my VPC.
The problem is that if I try to establish a connection from an EC2 to the Strongswan instance the connection always fails.

```
The routes on 2.2.2.2:
172.0.0.0/16 dev Tunnel1 scope link metric 100 
172.0.0.0/16 dev Tunnel2 scope link metric 200
```

```
Iptables mangle rules:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MARK       esp  --  <aws-endpoint>  2.2.2.2      MARK set 0x64
MARK       esp  --  <aws-endpoint>  2.2.2.2      MARK set 0xc8

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
```

Checking with tshark on 2.2.2.2, I noticed that SYN/ACK isn't reaching the EC2, causing retransmissions and eventual failure.

Any idea why the SYN/ACK isn't reaching the EC2, which initiated the connection?